# Cannot call WCF service via net.tcp binding from IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

a) I have a WCF service, self hosted in a windows service, on Windows 2008 R2 machine A.  Its using a net.tcp binding.  Not port shared.

b) I have an ASP.Net website running on IIS on Windows 2008 R2 machine B (as ApplicationPoolIdentity, although I doubt relevant), that must call the service on Machine A.

I get this error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:01:00'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Which looks like a connectivity/firewall issue, but it's not, as:

c) I made a simple winforms app that uses the exact same code as (b) to call the WCF service on machine A. It succeeds when run on Machine B.

Both (b) and (c) create the WCF proxy in code, without using anything in the web.config/app.config.   They're both using the same URI for the endpoint

So there must be some difference here between IIS making a net.tcp call and a regular app...? Is there anything security related around this?

I've tried enabling all the windows services you normally need for hosting within IIS (WAS, net adapter listener, port sharing...) just in case, but made no difference.

Many thanks for input.

Comment: Hi,
did you add tcp protocol and a tcp binding in your website in IIS ? non HTTP binding requires WAS under IIS.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand this, but just checking- you do understand IIS is the client, not the server in this config right?

Comment: Oups, read too fast. Sorry. did you try another account for application pool ? Depending on your binding, the default security mode can be Windows. Running from a WebForm (with your account) is different for hosting in IIS.

Comment: Thanks yes - changed to SYSTEM account - no difference.

Comment: looks strange. i don't really have an answer. maybe can you disable set securitymode to None (just in case) or changing your binding for testing purpose.

Comment: tcp binding has no security by default no?

Comment: from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx), *The NetTcpBinding generates a run-time communication stack by default, which uses transport security, TCP for message delivery, and a binary message encoding. This binding is an appropriate Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) system-provided choice for communicating over an Intranet.*

Comment: @Frank - nope.  Will be returning to it in a few weeks only.

Comment: try setting receive timeout for the service hosted on iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the binding security to None.

```
  <netTcpBinding >
    <binding name="MyServer" >
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```